# Scraping a particular dictionary format to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure which looks something like this:

```
data = [{'organization': {'id': 14, 'description': 'France'},
'distribution': True,
'forAttention': True},
{'organization': {'id': 38, 'description': 'Netherlands'},
'distribution': True,
'forAttention': True},
{'organization': {'id': 31, 'description': 'Poland'},
'notifying': True,
'origin': True},
{'organization': {'id': 17, 'description': 'United Kingdom'},
'distribution': True}]
```

(Please note this is just 1 example with 4 organizations, but this number can vary)

I want to put this information for the organizations in a single row of a dataframe something like this:

```
>> df
Origin_ct      Notifying_ct     Distribution_ct       ForAttention_ct
Poland         Poland           France, Netherlands,  France, Netherlands
                                United Kingdom
```

The idea is for every organization - check if it has a True value and put it in the respective column for the dataframe. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Origin_ct','Notifying_ct','Distribution_ct','ForAttention_ct'])
origin_ct = []
notifying_ct = []
distribution_ct = []
forattention_ct = []
for organization in data:
    country = organization['organization']['description']
    if 'origin' in organization.keys() and organization['origin']:
        origin_ct.append(country)
    if 'notifying' in organization.keys() and organization['notifying']:
        notifying_ct.append(country)
    if 'distribution' in organization.keys() and organization['distribution']:
        distribution_ct.append(country)
    if 'forAttention' in organization.keys() and organization['forAttention']:
        forattention_ct.append(country)
```